# Sentence Construction for unexpected scenario

Tags: sentence-construction

My colleague had planed holiday but still he has come to office. I want to ask him about his leave how I can say?

a) Today you are not suppose to come office? aren't you?

b) Today you were not coming to office, why you came?

c) Today you would not be coming to office today, why you came?

Or is there any other polite way to asked?

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> Today you were not coming to office, why did you come?

That is correct but not really polite.

> I thought you were going on holiday today?

While this doesn't ask why he came to the office it implies you are wondering why he came.

> I didn't expect to see you at the office today, I thought you had a holiday.

While this doesn't ask a question it implies you want to know why he came to the office